# Awesomium on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, awesomium

Have anyone used to do with [Awesomium framework](http://awesomium.com/) on Mac OSX? I try to create a sample project and add code in main.m, but it has error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "Awesomium::WebCoreConfig::setCustomCSS(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you have any ideas for this error?

Answer (score 3):

`main.m` is an Objective-C source file and `std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&` is a C++ class.

Change the name of `main.m` to `main.mm`, making it a Objective-C++ source file and try again.

Comment: @karl.winsley OK, are you linking with the library?

Comment: Yes. I had used this link(http://support.awesomium.com/kb/getting-started/setting-up-on-mac-osx) to set up framework and include them

Comment: When I call Awesomium::WebCoreConfig config, it's ok. But I use setCustomCSS like this config.setCustomCSS("::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }");
it has this error

Comment: @karl.winsley OK, please post the complete link statement from Xcode.

Comment: What complete link do you need?

Comment: @karl.winsley Well I'd like to see every compile and link statement excuted by Xcode to see if I can find the issue.  You haven't provided enough information at the moment to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I don't has that error anymore. But it has another error. Haizz

Answer (score 2):

Awesomium is 32 bit only (a current limitation of chromium) while Apple's compiler defaults to 64 bits these days. 
You have to compile your app using `-m32` (or if using Xcode setting the architecture to 32 bit only as in the link the OP posted)

Example:

```
clang -m32 awe_test.cpp -o test -framework Awesomium -F$(DIR_WHERE_I_HAVE_AWESOMIUM) -I$(DIR_WHERE_I_HAVE_AWESOMIUM)
```